# How can I tweak OLA Hallagren's backup script to include encrypted backups?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016, database-administration, database-backups

I have the latest version of OLA Hallagrens backup script.The code being ran is:

```
EXECUTE [Master].[dbo].[DatabaseBackup] @Databases = 'MyUser_DB', @Directory = N'\\SFTPIPAdress\Backups', @BackupType = 'FULL', @Verify = 'N', @CleanupTime = 720, @CheckSum = 'Y', @FileName = '{DatabaseName}_{Year}{Month}{Day}_{FileNumber}.{FileExtension}',@Compress='Y', @Encrypt = 'Y', @EncryptionAlgorithm = 'AES_256', @ServerCertificate = 'DBBackupCertificate', @LogToTable = 'Y'
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
The backup cannot be performed because 'ENCRYPTION' was requested after the media was formatted with an incompatible structure. To append to this media set, either omit 'ENCRYPTION' or create a new media set by using WITH FORMAT in your BACKUP statement. If you use WITH FORMAT on an existing media set, all its backup sets will be overwritten.    
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

This looked like a recent [bug](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/186).The user was able to resolve their issue by adding the log to table param which I'm already making use of. Not sure where to go from here or what options I have.

It seems like the existing media set is not encrypted and can't add an encrypted one or the sequence/chain is being broken.

Comment: In your case, it looks like it's due to your passing in a custom `@FileName` parameter which will make it so that more than one backupset will exist in a file on disk. If this is something that you rely on, my suggestion would be to rename your existing file so that when the backup next kicks off, it will see that there is no file by that name on disk and it will initialize a new one with encryption turned on.

Comment: I think I follow you. To be sure you are saying that I am having issues because the physical device name is the same?

For example, the backup file taken today will have DBName_20190211 as the name. But doesn't this imply that as long as I'm taking one full backup a day that I will be fine?

Comment: Kind of. The Hallengren script is pretty smart in that it looks to see if a file by the name that it's going to backup to already exists and, if it does, will append to it. Which is what I think you're running into by specifying a value for `@FileName` that only allows for granularity to one day. If you take more than one backup in a day, it will append to the file. Take a look at the backup data (located in `backupset` and `backupmediafamily`, both in msdb) for what's going on. I suspect that you already have a file from the same day as you're attempting that has a mismatch on encryption.